# ECharts animation bug when updating data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, echarts

I found a bug in ECharts when updating data while animation and dataZoom are set to true.

Here is the initial chart:

[image]

And this is what I get when I update the data:

[image]

[image]

The bug is not related to my data because as soon as I move the zoom slider, the chart becomes normal again.

Also, if I set {animation: false} or remove dataZoom from the option everything works fine so the bug should be associated with animation or dataZoom options.

I was wondering if this is a bug in ECharts library or I am doing something wrong.

Thanking you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same as [issue#10228 - wrong line display after setOption()](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/10228)

I hope the new [replace-merge](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/pull/12987) mode in version 5.x can fix this